# Swift Vapor Fluent updating an existing row

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor

I know you can do `Model.delete() and Model.save()`

Is there a way to update an existing row?

Answer (score 1):

In Fluent 2.0 there is a property added to every Entity/Model:

`let storage = Storage()`

This object is holding additional information for each entity, if `storage.exists` is `true` it will update data when you call `save()` instead of trying to insert new item to database.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Fluent's code, I believe it saves the fields that are "dirty".
So, you would have to do something like this:

```
let user = try User.find(42)
user.name = "Other Name"
try user.save()
```

I didn't try this, but I'll do it soon.